# Can I use a text field to create an Account object in a trigger?

Tags: trigger, soql

I am adding an `after insert` trigger on lead, where if there is a value (id) in a custom field (fromAccount__c), that specific account with said id, will be deleted.

- this is in order to solve [How to Convert a Contact back to lead - and delete the old contact and account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-convert-a-contact-back-to-lead-and-delete-the-old-contact-and-account)

So, my trigger started like this, but I don't understand how to get the account inserted correctly into the `accountsToDelete`

- Should I actually create the Account Object?

> trigger deleteAccountFromContact on Lead (after insert) {
>
> ////////////////////////////////////// // This trigger deletes the
>   account that the contact // was converted from.
>
> ```
> if (Trigger.new.fromAccount__c != null)
> {
>
>     List<Account> accountsToDelete = new List<Account>();
>
>     Account tempAccount = new Account(id=Trigger.new.fromAccount__c);
>
>     accountsToDelete.add( tempAccount ) ;
>
>     delete accountsToDelete;
> } }
> ```

Another option to make this a more SOQL trigger will be to use :

Account tempAcc = [Select Account.id from Account where AccountId =:Trigger.new.fromAccount__c]

But I get the error:

**Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST at line 15 column 81**

> if (Trigger.new.fromAccount__c != null)
>
> ```
> {
>
>     List<Account> accountsToDelete = new List<Account>();
>
>     Account tempAccount = [Select Account.id from Account where AccountId =:Trigger.new.fromAccount__c]
>
>     accountsToDelete.add( tempAccount ) ;
>
>     delete accountsToDelete;
> } }
> ```

- Can I create an account based on a text field of ID?
- should I make this a more SOQL valued trigger?
- else what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
 Account tempAccount = [Select Id from Account where Id =:Trigger.new[0].fromAccount__c]
```

and then your second option should work.  I don't quite follow why you were trying to create an Account in the first approach?

Also - the Trigger.new collection is just that - a collection.  You can't treat it like a single record.  In this case you're assuming there's only one record, so you actually want

```
:Trigger.new[0].fromAccount__c
```